# PHP ctype extension not installed (mac)

Tags: php, macos, yii

I'm trying to get a base install of Yii running on my mac to do PHP development in the Yii framework.  However, installing Yii requires Composer.  Composer install fails saying that ctype is not installed.

I'm running php 5.5 supplied by AMPPS.

Installing composer:
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=bin

Results in this message:

**"#!/usr/bin/env php
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:
The ctype extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-ctype
The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl"**

I can work with https which would lead me to believe that the openssl message is bogus and the php install manual (http://php.net/manual/en/ctype.installation.php) would lead me to believe that ctype is installed and enabled too.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Command line PHP and Apache's PHP may have been compiled separately (ie, they are not the same).  My guess would be that if you have openssl working locally on websites, it wasn't compiled with the php-cli that Composer is using.